# Logging Global variable inside the function Block immediately before redeclaration going undefined: Should not it take the Global Variable Value?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

```
let pages =100;
let pageFunction=()=>{
 console.log(pages);
 const pages = "20";
 //console.log(pages);
}
pageFunction();
```

Output:
Uncaught ReferenceError: pages is not defined
    at pageF (:3:13)
    at :1:1

Comment: Variable declarations apply to the whole scope, even if execution hasn't reached them yet.

Comment: As you see, it does *not* log `undefined`?

Answer (score 1):

According to Mozilla "The let statement declares a block scope local variable, optionally initializing it to a value."   Also "At the top level of programs and functions, let, unlike var, does not create a property on the global object."

See 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let for more information.

This means that in the code you gave you effectively create an implicit global variable pages, as *let pages* is not really global, but restricted to the scope it is in.